# How the app icon is added inside my iOS app?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

When I look my Info.plist their is nothing about icon in it, but after I deployed the app, I look in it for the the Info.plist and I can see that it's contain :

```
    <key>CFBundleIcons</key>
<dict>
    <key>CFBundlePrimaryIcon</key>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleIconFiles</key>
        <array>
            <string>AppIcon60x60</string>
        </array>
        <key>CFBundleIconName</key>
        <string>AppIcon</string>
    </dict>
</dict>
<key>CFBundleIcons~ipad</key>
<dict>
    <key>CFBundlePrimaryIcon</key>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleIconFiles</key>
        <array>
            <string>AppIcon60x60</string>
            <string>AppIcon76x76</string>
        </array>
        <key>CFBundleIconName</key>
        <string>AppIcon</string>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

I can see that also the root folder of my app contain 2 files :

- AppIcon60x60@2x.png
- AppIcon76x76@2x~ipad.png

but nothing in my project, in deployment option, is speaking about those 2 icons. so where they are coming from ? what process add the CFBundleIconFiles key value to the info.plist ?

I want to specify myself the icon (and not from the ide of delphi, I want to update myself the info.plist, and i want to deploy myself the icon), how can I do ?

Comment: "I want to specify myself the icon (and not from the ide of delphi". Why? 
On the Mac, check the `(appname).launchscreen/Assets/AppIcon.appiconset/Contents.json` file under the `scratch-dir/(username)-(profilename)` folder. It details what ends up in assets.car inside the Payload of the .ipa

Comment: thanks dave, but I would like to deploy my own launchScreen and my own Asset.car, but seam it's not possible anymore from Delphi Sydney :(

Comment: You still haven't specified *why*, and you don't even describe what problem you are trying solve. Doing so can often reveal alternative solutions. As for creating your own `Assets.car`, you're probably aware it's not trivial and involves invoking commands on the Mac and copying it back to the machine with Delphi on it. I did this for Delphi 10.3.3 when the 1024x1024 issue raised its ugly head but was solved in 10.4

Comment: @DaveNottage yes, it's just the way I was doing before sydney. yes it's not trivial (I was force to create a batch file that send command to the mac to create the assets.car). the new way with Sydney look more simple and I must update my old flow to work with the new sydney flow, that is not really a bad think! The only think that block me a little is that in sydney  I can not configure the path where the directory LaunchScreen.TemplateiOS will be created: please vote here: https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-33503

Comment: "the new way with Sydney look more simple and I must update my old flow to work with the new sydney flow". It's simpler because Sydney does the work of the creation of `Assets.car`. Again, you're not describing the *actual* problem, so I'm bowing out at this point

Comment: @DaveNottage : I was simply trying to keep my old flow that I made in pre-sydney, so uploading myself all icons, building myself the assets.car, all launchscreens, etc. definitively not the best way in sydney

Answer (score 0):

I only have a partial answer but hopefully will point you in the right direction.
The default `info.plist.TemplateiOS.xml` contains:

```
<%VersionInfoPListKeys%>
<%ExtraInfoPListKeys%>
<%StoryboardInfoPListKey%>
```

Each of these is expanded with information from your project settings.  By deleting the corresponding key, you can replace it with your own settings.  It might take some trial and error to determine which one inserts the icons.